# background image not loading in external CSS ( relative path used)

Tags: html, css

what the CSS file looks like:

---

### h1{

### .....
}

### body{

## background-image: url(/img/back.png) ;

### }

---

what the files hierarchy looks like:

- img(file containing the images)

---

```
 -back.png(the background image i want to keep as background)
```

- .css
- .html

i am not sure why the image is not loading even though i have used relative path to the css file as suggested by the asnwers in past questions similar to this. if anyone can help thank you.
The rest of CSS is working just a problem with this background-image issue

Comment: try putting path in quotes

Comment: hello, i have tried , but it still didn't work.

Comment: `./img/back.png`?

Comment: omg thank you very muc i can't believe it worked. thank you

Comment: I think there is problem with your relative path and also you are missing inverted commas. It works without inverted commas but it is recommended to use  those.Use single '.' before the path.
background-image: url('./img/back.png');

Comment: i see. thanks you for the answer. will keep it in mind to use commas.